# How to debug EKS on Fargate not sending logs to Cloudwatch

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-eks, aws-fargate, amazon-cloudwatchlogs

I have a cluster on EKS that uses a mix of Fargate and managed EC2 nodes. I'm wanting to implement native FluentBit logging for the containers running on Fargate nodes and have tried following these guides: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eks/latest/userguide/fargate-logging.html and https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/containers/fluent-bit-for-amazon-eks-on-aws-fargate-is-here/.

My cluster was originally an older version which didn't support native logging for Fargate, but as part of this I updated it to version 1.18 / 7.

However no logs are showing up in CloudWatch.

The pod annotations look correct:

```
Annotations:          CapacityProvisioned: 0.25vCPU 0.5GB
                      Logging: LoggingEnabled
                      kubernetes.io/psp: eks.privileged
Status:               Running
```

I'm not able to find any error logs anywhere. Is there any way to figure out what issue might be going on?

Answer (score 3):

I did not find any way to debug this issue, but did solve it. I'm using Terraform to define infrastructure, and my FluentBit config was indented in the Terraform code. This will silently break logging. Removing the indentation fixed the issue.

Comment: Same thing happened to me! Thanks for your answer :)